# Permissive Math Library for Parameter Statistics in C++

Tags: c++, statistics

I am looking for recommendations for a C++ math library, with a permissive licence, well suited to calculating a wide variety of statistics on segmentations of timebased parameter data.

I would be particularly interested in anything that can quantify properties of the curve shapes as well as the raw data set.

Comment: Hi Casey, welcome to *Computational Science*. Could you please update your question with details of which libraries you have so far tried and what your problems were with those libraries. It will help people gain a better insight into what might or might not be suitable for you.

Comment: A quick look over on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) suggests that [C++ libraries for statistical computing](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7358/11083) might be of use.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Trilinos looks interesting. I have not used anything yet, though I spent a few hours looking to find most projects are either GPL or commercial, which rules out something like R.  I'm a composer, my math skills are very limited so I'm looking for something that help me derive a battery of measurements (statistics of different parameters) preferably with an interface where most of the math is abstracted.  I also looked at boost, but I don't have the experience to compare quality.

Comment: To follow on @MarkBooth 's suggestion, the Boost C++ libraries are permissively licensed and have basic statistical distributions.  However it sound like the Question is more about parameter estimation and/or curve fitting.

Comment: I'm dealing with both unordered sets and parameters.  Curve fitting is one half of it. If I were to use boost to pull single value measurement parameters from ordered and unordered sets what aspects of the Boost:math would I be looking at? For curves, I was thinking of using googles new ceres for fititng, though I don't know if that is appropriate.  I'm not adverse to learning some math to use these but I don't really know where to start but I'm refactoring software that I rely on for work so I need something to jump in with and figure it out as I go

Comment: Hi again Casey. Stack exchange doesn't work like web forums you might be used to. Comments are here to help you make you question better, so when we ask for more information we would normally expect the *question to be edited* to add that information, making it clear within the context of the question. Thus, when our queries are addressed, we can clear up the comments thread (i.e delete our comments) and just be left with a clearer question.